# Accessor/Mutator do Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Substituição de "," por "." pelo Mutator do Laravel Retorna vazia e não salva no banco.

**ProdutosController**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Prettus\Validator\Contracts\ValidatorInterface;
use Prettus\Validator\Exceptions\ValidatorException;
use App\Http\Requests\ProdutoCreateRequest;
use App\Http\Requests\ProdutoUpdateRequest;
use App\Repositories\ProdutoRepository;
use App\Validators\ProdutoValidator;
use App\Services\ProdutoService;

class ProdutosController extends Controller
{
    protected $repository;

    protected $service;

    public function __construct(ProdutoRepository $repository, ProdutoService $service)
    {
        $this->repository   = $repository;
        $this->service      = $service;
    }

        public function store(ProdutoCreateRequest $request)
    {
        $request = $this->service->store($request->all());
        $produto = $request['success'] ? $request['data'] : null ;

        session()->flash('success', [
            'success'   => $request['success'],
            'messages'  => $request['messages'],
        ]);
        return redirect()->route('admin.produtos.create');
    }   
}
```

**ProdutoService**

```
namespace App\Services;

use App\Repositories\ProdutoRepository;
use App\Validators\ProdutoValidator;
use Illuminate\Routing\Matching\ValidatorInterface;
use Exception;

class ProdutoService
{
    private $repository;
    private $validator;


    public function __construct(ProdutoRepository $repository, ProdutoValidator $validator)
    {
        $this->repository = $repository;
        $this->validator = $validator;
    }

    public function store($data)
    {
        try
        {
            $produto = $this->repository->create($data);
            return [
                'success'   => true,
                'messages'  => 'Produto cadastrado com Sucesso',
                'data'      => $produto,
            ];
        }
        catch(Exception $e)
        {
            dd($e);
            return [
                'success'   => false,
                'messages'  => 'Erro de execução',
            ];
        }
    }    
}
```

**Produto** Model

```
namespace App\Entities;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
use Prettus\Repository\Contracts\Transformable;
use Prettus\Repository\Traits\TransformableTrait;

class Produto extends Model implements Transformable
{
    use TransformableTrait;
    use SoftDeletes;

    public $timestamps = true;

    protected $table = 'produtos';

    protected $fillable = [
        'titulo', 'status', 'console', 'genero', 'classificacao', 'custo', 'venda', 'desconto',
        'indatepromo', 'outdatepromo', 'quantidade', 'descricao', 'produtora', 'lancamento',
        'idioma', 'legenda', 'onplayers', 'offplayers', 'obs1', 'obs2', 'obs3', 'video',
    ];

    protected $hidden = ['status', 'custo'];

    /// CUSTO TROCA VIRGULA POR PONTO
    public function setCustoAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['custo'] = str_replace(",", ".", $value);
    }
    public function getCustoAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['custo'] = str_replace(".", ",", $value);
    }

    /// VENDA TROCA VIRGULA POR PONTO
    public function setVendaAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['venda'] = str_replace(",", ".", $value);
    }
    public function getVendaAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['venda'] = str_replace(".", ",", $value);
    }

    /// PROMOÇÃO TROCA VIRGULA POR PONTO
    public function setDescontoAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['desconto'] = str_replace(",", ".", $value);
    }
    public function getDescontoAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['desconto'] = str_replace(".", ",", $value);
    }
}
```

**ProdutoRepository**

```
namespace App\Repositories;

use Prettus\Repository\Contracts\RepositoryInterface;

/**
 * Interface ProdutoRepository.
 *
 * @package namespace App\Repositories;
 */
interface ProdutoRepository extends RepositoryInterface
{
    //
}
```

Comment: Deve colar o código, não utilize apenas imagens

Comment: Por favor cole o seu controlador e o model acho que sei qual é o problema

Comment: @JorgeCosta Pronto amigo postei apenas os códigos. postei também o service.

Comment: Por favor mostre o código para ProdutoRepository $repository  em particular o método create.

Comment: @JorgeCosta Eu uso o L5-Repository... só consigo ver ele vazio e a interface

Comment: @jorgeCosta e também quando eu envio os dados sem a necessidade de trocar a virgula por pontos, os dados são cadastrado normalmente

Comment: Penso que L5-Repository  é o seu problema,  não deve estar a respeitar os mutators, deve fazer um teste simples crie um modelo básico sem recurso ao L5-Repository coloque os seus mutators e use o método create directamente no modelo

Comment: @JorgeCosta Com o Repository que criei funcionou corretamente, realmente é o L5 que ta bugando.. agora preciso descobrir como desimplementar essa bagaça e tirar do meu laravel,

Comment: Ou posso continuar com ele, e só usar em outras ocasiões também né.

Comment: Sim claro, por favor considere minha resposta como correctamente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A implementação do *Mutator* (set) está correcta

A implementação do *Accessor* (get) deve devolver um valor

Substituindo

```
public function getCustoAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['custo'] = str_replace(".", ",", $value);
    }
```

por

```
public function getCustoAttribute($value)
    {
       return  $this->attributes['custo'] = str_replace(".", ",", $value);
    }
```

Comment: Mano descobri o problema.. o erro persistia em não ter colocado "Return" no Mutator lá no Model da aplicação.. depois que coloquei Return $this->attributes['custo'] = str_replace(",", ".", $value); funcionou direitinho agora o//

Comment: Mas essa não a forma correcta de criação do mutator já que é um setter

Comment: Corrigi a resposta indicado a designação correcta Accessor